# How tall are the monoliths?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Here is an example of an input of **monoliths**. There are 4 in this example.

```
  _
 | |        _
 | |  _    | |
 | | | |   | |     _
_| |_| |___| |____| |_
```

The first monolith is 4 units high, the second is 2, the third is 3, and the last is 1.

## The task

Your program should output the heights of the monoliths in order from left to right. The output format can be in any sort of list or array.

## Notes

- The input can be taken as any dimensional string, list of strings, or list of characters.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **lowest bytes wins**.
- You are to assume that monoliths always have the same width, and are always at least 1 `_` away from another.
- They can come in any height, and in any quantity.

## I/O

```
  _
 | |        _
 | |  _    | |
 | | | |   | |     _
_| |_| |___| |____| |_   >> [4,2,3,1]

           _
          | |
  _       | |
 | |  _   | |  _
_| |_| |__| |_| |_   >> [2,1,4,1]


 _   _   _ 
| |_| |_| |_____   >> [1,1,1]

____________________   >> undefined behavior

 _
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |   >> [11]

     _       _       _       _       _
 _  | |  _  | |  _  | |  _  | |  _  | |
| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |  >> [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

Comment: May I assume the input is right padded with spaces?

Comment: Is your `[10]` monolith not `[11]` ?

Comment: Wouldn't the undefined one just be an empty array?

Comment: @isaacg yes, that would be okay

Comment: @SolomonUcko technically yes, though to make it simpler for all languages I decided to not have them deal with it.

Comment: Ok. So basically, you _can_ implement it like that, but don't have to?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes, exactly. Primarily because some algorithms might fail at that test, and have to create more code just for that exception. Which drives the average byte count up (which is no fun).

Comment: I see, that makes sense.

Comment: Bit late to ask, but does the spec guarantee that all monoliths have a single `_` on top as in the test cases, or merely that they always have the same width *per input*?

Answer (score 16):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (8?) 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ỵ=”|Sḟ0m2
```

A monadic link accepting a list of characters as specified and returning a list of integers.

Note: **8 bytes** if a list of strings, one per line, was really intended to be an allowed input format - just remove the `Ỵ`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i22jxrm1gQ/3DHfINfo////ChAQzwWhaxRqqMNCMRIigGETVB1cbzyyOEQLTGM8F5AVHx8PImE4HkqCKQA)**

#### How?

```
Ỵ=”|Sḟ0m2 - Link: list of characters, s
Ỵ         - split at newlines
  ”|      - literal '|'
 =        - equals (vectorises)
    S     - sum (vectorises, hence counts the number of '|' in every column)
     ḟ0   - filter out zeros (only keep the results from the sides of the towers)
       m2 - modulo index with 2 (keep only the left side measurements)
```

Comment: I don't know, but is [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i22jxrm1gQ/3DHfINfo////ChAQzwWhaxRqqMNCMRIigGETVB1cbzyyOEQLTGM8F5AVHx8PImE4HkrCqHgoGwQB) okay?

Comment: @V.Courtois I don't see why not, since we'll probably never get such input.

Comment: Okay, it's because I saw that some other answers take it in count

Comment: @V.Courtois the input you suggested does not fit the specification, similarly adding underscores in the sky, part-way up monoliths, or underground would probably break many other submissions.

Comment: Down-voter - would you care to explain your reasons?

Comment: @JonathanAllan just noticed ^^

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ỴṚZi€”_ỊÐḟ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i0Pd86KynzUtOZRw9z4h7u7Dk94uGP@o4aZ////V1CI51KoAUIogPHiQRwgC8KFKIApi@eKBzLBOB5KgikA)

Comment: Wow, you answered that fast.

Comment: @Graviton Hehe one should always have [this page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) open somewhere. ;)

Comment: Explanation, please!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*
*-1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

```js
a=>a.map((b,i)=>b.replace(/_/g,(_,j)=>o[j]=a.length+~i),o=[])&&o.filter(x=>x)
```

Takes input as an array of strings.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
a=>a.map((b,i)=>b.replace(/_/g,(_,j)=>o[j]=a.length+~i),o=[])&&o.filter(x=>x)
I.value="           _\n          | |\n  _       | |\n | |  _   | |  _\n_| |_| |__| |_| |_"
```

```html
<textarea id=I rows=7 cols=30></textarea><br><button onclick="O.value=`[${f(I.value.split`\n`).join`, `}]`">Run</button> <input id=O disabled>
```

Comment: 78 bytes: `a=>a.map((x,y)=>x.replace(/_/g,(_,z)=>c[z]=a.length-y-1),c=[])&&c.filter(n=>n)`

Comment: @Shaggy Nice, I totally didn't think of using `replace`. Thanks!

Comment: `-i-1` => `+~i`

Comment: @l4m2 Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## C++, <s>171</s> 169 bytes

```
#import<vector>
#import<iostream>
int f(std::vector<std::string>s){for(int a,j,i=0,k=s.size()-1;a=s[k][i];++i)if(a==32){for(j=0;(a=s[k-++j][i])-95;);std::cout<<j<<" ";}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVDbboMwDH3nK6zsJREwdZv2sCbhR7oKIQZVqLiIpH0Y49tZLqQrlVpprSPHdnLic@K86@Jdnk/Tk6i7tlfsWOSq7ZPA16KVqi@yOglEo6DEUn2t1w7EbK6vRbNLJBnKtscGlEVVJPgq2nP5LMV3gUn8QjMuN/vtRmxpGAoiSpxx/vbqHlV8RbEFxGFYGRCJP94poZYgbw@KsYoxBIiO42Qo6kw0mARDANquSQJVSAUcBgSQogjBj16z/dWpKXXmDxzIQw0u1YX1dN5tQCO17CU2NGdagTFAnw1y12caYEF@spnbCVlqsWcuWejwyb81mH7OdT/fZf7UHd1ck4f2e6boJ3U1mvmlcBrhjXgxhht@qTQYp18)

## C++ (GCC), 150 bytes

*Thanks to @aschepler!*

```
#import<vector>
#import<iostream>
int f(auto s){for(int a,j,i=0,k=s.size()-1;a=s[k][i];++i)if(a==32){for(j=0;(a=s[k-++j][i])-95;);std::cout<<j<<" ";}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVDLboMwELzzFSv3Yguo0lY9NLb5kTRCiEJkIjDCTg@lfDv1A6dJpEZqsmi9D493hyn7Pt2V5Tw/iLaXg2afVanlkEWhFlLpoSraLBKdhhoXBy1BkbGWA7adImkSwVfJnqtHJb4qTNInWnC12W83YkvjWBBhXnH@8uwfNXxFsQOkcdxYEEnfXimhSn@s16U8aMYaxhAgOk2zXdEWosMkGiMw5lCeJHO5oSe6XQa6Uho4jAggRwmCb/Mt9lvntjRZaHhQgFpcbgrn@XK6gCbqttfYrjnhCowBeu@Qvz7hAGfLj7bs9kTOubieT854hOTfHOw872ZemLL81A3T/JC7zltUDEr9Ga1@ORwlvBIvZLjil0yjaf4B)

Comment: If using g++, you can use the non-standard `f(auto s)` and specify it takes any random-access container of random-access containers of `char`.

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, 29 bytes

```
{0~⍨↑+/(⌈/⍴¨⍵)↑¨(⍳≢⍵)×⌽⍵='_'}
```

Run with `⎕IO←0`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQb/04BktUHdo94Vj9omautrPOrp0H/Uu@XQike9WzWBQodWaDzq3fyocxGIf3j6o569QIaterx67f//2UC96goK8eoK6go1QAgFCH48iAtkwQQgimBKQerigRwwjoeSYEqd61HvqmyuNIVsLqgdCiiGwwHUbIhFqHaBxSAMFHtgDIQdAA)

**How?**

`⌽⍵='_'` - where `⍵` is `'_'`, top lines first

`×`- multiply by ...

`(⍳≢⍵)` - the range of `⍵` (zero indexed)

`↑¨` - for each line, pad with zeros by ...

`(⌈/⍴¨⍵)` - the maximal length

`↑+/` - sum the rows zipped and flatten

`0~⍨` - removes zeros

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
|Rζ'_δkJ®0‚K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/JkjP6fAO9fhzW7K9Dq0zeNQwy/v/fwWFeC6FGiCEAhgvHsQBsiBciAKYsniueCATjOOhJJgCAA)

`ζ` has been replaced by `.Bø` on TIO since it hasn't been pulled there yet.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8 - <s>229 Bytes</s> 213 Bytes

```
s->{Map<Integer,Integer> m=new TreeMap();String[] l=s.split("\n");for(int i=0,j=-1;i<l.length-1;++i){s=l[i];while((j=s.indexOf("_",j+1))>=0){m.put(j,i);}}for(int i:m.values()){System.out.print(l.length-i-1+",");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVFNU4MwEL3zK3Y4JUIz7VVK7x6qh3qrHSbStA2GwJDQ6iC/HZdPtZ56MLBk92Xz8l5I@JnPslzoZP/WyDTPCgsJYqy0UrG7wHFixY2BNZe6cgCktqI48FjAI7Q1wDmTe4jJxhZSH4HTANEaA19juZUxdmoIoTGzVbXm@fIBKY6i8Id5BWmoxQWeCyFwmdCgp9ruQIWGmVxJS9wX7dLgkBUEBYAM534SzhaBXCqmhD7aExaeJ2llQrWVu@BykkoQkiCB1Hvx/nQgbuT6ibegdBXOaZWyvLQk8SUN6nrivU/ZmatSGEJptfkwVqQsKy3LUZAl01lytvBc3223NmgXneblq0Kng@HuSlK8MTJZ4cXR0MrpbgxAs5g4LkCEtjxMPvEZxi8oahHMfmB967hh6I6w7iIavt3kOvgz@hOvvShNprVRDFxLmMa3gl7RH1Ed3CfXgsbkNjEtXx8938gyuLuVbSL5vwRGSbXj1M0X)

**Ungolfed:**

```
public static void foo(String input)
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap(); // Raw types!!
    String[] lines = input.split("\n");

    for (int i = 0, j = -1; i < lines.length - 1; ++i)
    {
        input = lines[i];

        while ((j = input.indexOf("_", j + 1)) >= 0)
        {
            map.put(j, i);
        }
    }

    for(int i:map.values())
    {
        System.out.print(lines.length - i - 1 + ",");
    }
}
```

Woo, first post. Any help improving it would be great. <s>I *know* I can get rid of that `indexOf` written twice.</s> Knew it! I toyed with the idea of changing the types in the map from Integer to Long but I think that's a dead end.

---

<sub>I know there is [a much, much better Java 8 solution already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129130/61976), but that takes `char[][]` as input which I think is easier to work with in this case than String.</sub>

Comment: You haven't included the imports (they're required for Java answers). Don't use a `Map` but an `int[]` (maybe initialized to `new int[99]`?).  No need for a space after `String[] l`: `String[]l` works the same and is shorter. Use `println(l.length-i-1)` instead of `println(l.length-i-1+",")`. Don't initialize `j`: just write: `,j;`. If you use a `int[]` as suggested earlier, declare like this: `int m[]=new int[99],i=0,j;` and remove the declaration from the `for-loop`.

Comment: _OlivierGrégoire_ is indeed right about the required import for Map. As for some golfing of your current code with Map, you can change it to this: `import java.util.*;s->{Map m=new TreeMap();String[]a=s.split("\n");int l=a.length-1,j=-1,i=j;for(;++i<l;)for(s=a[i];(j=s.indexOf("_",j+1))>=0;m.put(j,i));for(Object o:m.values())System.out.println(l-(int)o);}`. No need for the `<Integer,Integer>` of the map when you can cast to `int`; `a.length-1` is used twice, so you can use a variable for it; by putting everything inside for-loops you can get rid of all brackets. Oh, and welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! Converting the contents of that first for loop to a bodyless for loop was inspiring! Super clever.

Comment: @Michael You're welcome. :) Oh, and if you haven't seen it yet: [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Helped me a lot when I first started (and still does sometimes).

Answer (score 5):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 11 bytes

```
⊢⇌⍉⊚⍉⇌⌕"_ "
```

[Try it!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__WyIgIF8gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIgogIiB8IHwgICAgICAgIF8gICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAiIHwgfCAgXyAgICB8IHwgICAgICAgICAgICIKICIgfCB8IHwgfCAgIHwgfCAgICAgXyAgIF8gIgogIl98IHxffCB8X19ffCB8X19fX3wgfF98IHwiXQoK4oqi4oeM4o2J4oqa4o2J4oeM4oyVIl8gIgo=)

**Explanation:**

```
      ⌕"_ " # Mark the locations of the tower tops
    ⍉⇌      # Rotate the array 90° clockwise
   ⊚        # Get the coordinates of the marked (non-zero) elements, going top to bottom
⊢⇌⍉         # Take the second column of the coordinates
```

(here's how the array looks before and after `⌕"_ "`)

```
["  _                      "
 " | |        _            "
 " | |  _    | |           "
 " | | | |   | |     _   _ "
 "_| |_| |___| |____| |_| |"]

[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Welcome to code golf SE teeth eator

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>48</s> 38 bytes

```
^
¶
{`(¶.*)*¶_(.*¶)+
$#2 $&
}`¶.
¶
G`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/juvQNq7qBI1D2/S0NLUObYvX0AOSmtpcKspGCipqXLUJQBmQGvcEvf//FeK5ahRqFKAAyokHsYEsMA8iDVMEVhEPwvFQEkwBAA) Link includes first example. Explanation: A line is prefixed which will collect the results. As each column is repeatedly deleted in turn, those that contains a `_` above ground level have the the number of remaining lines in the column counted. Finally the now blank lines are deleted. Edit: Saved 10 bytes thanks to inspriation from @FryAmTheEggman.

Comment: Nice, I had a [slightly shorter solution](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fOyFeQ0NP69A2TW1NLhVlIxVDLn8V5QQNextbDT2gWEyKNlDYkCs4PiHGRfv/fwWFeC6FGiCEABgnHsiGMCACYDacARSNBzLAGJUBAA), but it wouldn't work on large inputs since it would mess up my ability to sort them. Going column by column is a nice way to avoid that!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I switched to your method of counting the lines using the `_`s which makes much more sense than trying to use the `|`s, thanks!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Doesn't fix the problem, but your sorting stage can be simplified by dropping the lookbehind and sorting by `$.%\``, and the final stage can be `!\`\d+`. And if you change the first stage to a lookahead, you don't need to loop.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman And [here](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/XsPeVkNP69A2TW1NLhVlQy5/FeUEDXsbW42YFO0aPaAokAZLKCYAWf//KyjEcynUACEEwDjxQDaEAREAs@EMoGg8kAHGqAwA) is a fix to your approach, but it ends up at 46 bytes.

Comment: @MartinEnder 45 perhaps? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fw942XkNP69A2TW1NLhVlQy5/FeUEDXsbWw29mBQtoGBMijZYXDEByPr/X0EhnkuhBgghAMaJB7IhDIgAmA1nAEXjgQwwRmUAAA "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah yeah, nice idea. Still too long unfortunately :)

Comment: If we can assume that the input is padded to a rectangle, here is yet another approach that transposes the input (41 bytes): https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fhevQNhU91QQVLVsuf2WV4gQ9LhCXKzgh3t6WKx7EUedSTIhJ0f7/X0EhXgEL4FKoAUIIiMcUBwnBGQhxsBCcAZLkigcywRiVAQA

Comment: @MartinEnder I shall have to remember that transposition trick!

Comment: @Neil it's much easier for square inputs, because the linefeeds can remain in the correct position, so you only need that sorting stage and you can drop the `s` from it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda s:[x.index('_')for x in map(None,*s.split('\n')[::-1])if'_'in x[1:]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBDoIwDIbve4rGyzaDRDwukUfwBYAsGCAukUFcDxjl2bFsoBzs0q3t/n5L1z/x1tnThLVDB2fIOOcAmsGb1mJrpueEopAGwSrTTFPoXS@7PwgXMeahsOF9zeMCeQv3lRBswGvwg86y4Gy9XB7/ifQfo3LBWEMD59O9bK9VCU5lQ2xsVQ@Cay6b7gEDGAtt2YtLZ@to72LX3w0KnlsuM6UOSSFNQ2JSDVmiimKau3Du8v@p/KD9w1iE3es4AqQpvJIxt7uYlG2JAiNoBEo5fQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
z ·mb'_ fw0
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eiC3bWInXyBmdzA=&input=IiAgXwogfCB8ICAgICAgICBfCiB8IHwgIF8gICAgfCB8CiB8IHwgfCB8ICAgfCB8ICAgICBfCl98IHxffCB8X19ffCB8X19fX3wgfF8i)

#### Explanation

```
z ·mb'_ fw0   : Implicit input
z             : Rotate the input clockwise. This puts the "floor" against the left side.
  ·           : Split the 2D string into lines.
   m          : Replace each column (now row) X with
    b'_       :   the index of '_' in X (0-indexed). This gives us the output list, with
              :   0's and -1's mixed in representing the columns that are not monoliths.
        f     : Take only the items X where
         w0   :   max(X, 0) is truthy. Since 0 is falsy, this removes anything <= 0.
              : Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
0~⍨⍳∘≢+.×'_'=⊖
```

with `⎕IO←0`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQb/00Bk3aPeFY96Nz/qmPGoc5G23uHp6vHqto@6poHUAeXTFID0/0dtE9UVFOIVMIE6ENYAIRTEY0qAhZCUwCQgQjCJeLBEPJALxvFQEkypAwA)

---

This function train equivalent to `{((⍳≢⍵)+.×('_'=⊖⍵))~0}`

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, 133 bytes

```
param($s)$r=,0*($l=($s=$s-replace'\| \|',' 1 ')[0].Length);1..$s.Count|%{$z=$_-1;0..($l-1)|%{$r[$_]+=(''+$s[$z][$_]-as[int])}};$r-ne0
```

Looks like it's not very competitive; it does a regex replace to turn the towers into columns of 1, makes an array of 0 the length of the input string, then steps through the lines adding up the 1s.

Tests ready to run:

```
$s1 = @'
  _                   
 | |        _         
 | |  _    | |        
 | | | |   | |     _  
_| |_| |___| |____| |_
'@-split"`r?`n"


$s2 = @'
 _
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| | 
'@-split"`r?`n"

$s3 = @'
           _      
          | |       
  _       | |           
 | |  _   | |  _   
_| |_| |__| |_| |_ 
'@-split"`r?`n"


$s4 = @'
 _   _   _      
| |_| |_| |_____ 
'@-split"`r?`n"

$s5 = @'
     _       _       _       _       _ 
 _  | |  _  | |  _  | |  _  | |  _  | |
| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| | 
'@-split"`r?`n"
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>133</s> <s>117</s> <s>116</s> 114 bytes

```java
a->{for(int l=a.length-1,i=0,j;i<a[0].length;i++)if(a[l][i]<33){for(j=0;a[j][i]<33;j++);System.out.print(l-j+",");}}
```

Takes the input as a <s>`String[]`</s> `char[][]` (← saves 16 bytes).
-2 bytes  in exchange for less readable output thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* by changing `print(l-j+",")` to `println(l-j)`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##7VXBcoIwEL33K3a8CCMwdjxG@gf14pFhMimiJo3BgWing/l2mmJ6qQipCqdm2GGyeXm7mzwWRo7Ez/apYKv3KuGkKOCVUFE@AVAh03xNkhQW31OAY0ZXkDjJluRRHMVAXKT9Spt@CkkkTWABAkKoiP9SrrPc0RzAQxLwVGzk1n/2aDj1GKJzEk1j40V0MnHp2iERjyMaz2czt97LwikiETM@xDQKLT8Lme6C7CCDfa7JuXC4z1ykVIXOeewPb1znYdKpU97pgpyl1PhNnfW5GhEkjkg/4KecshzD2KsNm/djTHl1vItxjncyuJMFF@4pXhOvfV5/i3eNtysetoiHf/E0zXGH/3JNqVrnAA3iG/nXxshsapEZ3HXl7cduY@1H3s2Pe@S3kWk75n6ZtGN6kQXuuP5b5NBVatuX0EOZuDHMrdbjLdic6D9mIMwQPRjf@ft9zHp7X8TW/W/I9cc1n@HmRlLqSVVf)

```java
a->{                         // Method with character 2D-array parameter and no return-type
  for(int l=a.length-1,      //  Length of the 2D char-array - 1
      i=0,j;                 //  Index-integers
    i<a[0].length;i++)       //  Loop (1) over the 2D char-array
    if(a[l][i]<33){          //   If the base of the current column is a space
      for(j=0;a[j][i]<33;    //    Loop (2) over the cells in this column as long as
                             //    we encounter spaces (from top to bottom)
        j++                  //     And increase `j` every time, to go down the column
      );                     //    End of loop (2)
      System.out.println(l-j);
                             //    Print the amount of rows - `j`
    }                        //   End of if-block
                             //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
}                            // End of method
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but my idea for this challenge was to go top to bottom and look for `_` if found store it's location then order on that, ignoring the bottom row of course. Might help to save bytes...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That was my initial thought as well, but where do you want to store it in / order it? I originally thought a Map, but those are unsorted so you'll need a LinkedMap. In my head it all sounded a bit too much bytes, but if you can find a way to accomplish it shorter than this feel free to post an answer and I'll +1 it. :)

Comment: I only managed to get it down to 150 using Linq but there should be room for golfing it still.

Comment: In C# we have multidimensional arrays like: `new[,]` instead of the jagged array you are using as `new[][]`. If you have that in Java it could save you some bytes.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That's the way Java uses multidimensional arrays I'm afraid. `char[]` = char-array; `char[][]` = 2D char-array; `char[][][]` = 3D char-array; etc.

Comment: That's unfortunate we have both in C# so it comes in handy sometimes.

Comment: `System.out.println(l-j);` looks listy enough for me to spare 2 bytes. Also, in the explanation, you forgot to change `length()` into `length` (no incidence on the byte-count as it's correct in the submission).

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <del>75</del> 74 bytes

```hs
import Data.List;f=filter(>0).map(length.fst.span(<'!').reverse).transpose
```

The input is expected as a list of strings (rowwise).

Comment: Why use a semicolon after the import, when a newline is the same length and more idiomatic?

Comment: @Jules: Yeah, I usually do

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
&nxG2\&fx-Xz
```

Input is a char matrix, with `;` as row separator.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy2vwt0oRi2tQjei6v//aHWFeAUsQN1aQV2hBgihIB6LDFgMSQ1cBiIGk4mHyMQD@WAcDyXBlHosAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmfEOH1Xy2vwssoRi2tQjei6r@6rq6ueoRLyP9odYV4BSxA3VpBXaEGCKEgHosMWAxJDVwGIgaTiYfIxAP5YBwPJcGUeiwX0AkIEI9sFhzALYEIx2MVhrsJzkC1FsZQgNgZD7UtHmEETAXUfVDHxasrWIOkoCoopeAejkfzMiYN9lY8wkN4aHTn48HqsQA).

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>150</s> <s>144</s> 137 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>a.SelectMany((i,h)=>i.Select((c,w)=>new{c,w,d=a.Length-1-h}).Where(o=>o.c==95&o.d>0)).OrderBy(o=>o.w).Select(o=>o.d)
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<char[][], IEnumerable<int>> f = a =>
            a.SelectMany((i, h) => i.Select((c, w) => new { c, w, d = a.Length - 1 - h })
                                    .Where(o => o.c == 95 & o.d > 0))
             .OrderBy(o => o.w)
             .Select(o => o.d);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(f(new char[][]
        {
            "  _                 ".ToArray(),
            " | |       _        ".ToArray(),
            " | |  _   | |       ".ToArray(),
            " | | | |  | |    _  ".ToArray(),
            "_| |_| |__| |___| |_".ToArray(),
        })));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
ooYssqtO>)
```

Input is a padded character matrix.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz8/sri4sMTfTvP//2h1hXgFLEDdWkFdoQYIoSAeiwxYDEkNXAYiBpOJh8jEA/lgHA8lwZR6LAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda l:[s.index('_')+1for s in zip(*l[-2::-1])if'_'in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKrpYLzMvJbVCQz1eXVPbMC2/SKFYITNPoSqzQEMrJ1rXyMpK1zBWMzMNKA8ULo79X1CUmVeikabBFa2ugADxEEpdh0sBSbgGCJGE47EKg3nxMOF4qHA8kAfGcIZ6LJem5n8A)

Taking input as list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

## Uiua, <s>11</s> 12 bytes

```
▽↧\≠±../+=@|
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4pa94oanXOKJoMKxLi4vKz1AfAoKRiBbIiAgXyAgIF8gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAgICIgfCB8IHwgfCAgICBfICAgICAgICAgICAgIgogICAiIHwgfCB8IHwgICB8IHwgICAgICAgICBfICIKICAgIiB8IHwgfCB8ICAgfCB8ICAgICBfICB8IHwiCiAgICJffCB8X3wgfF9fX3wgfF9fX198IHxffCB8Il0K)

Annoyingly my original solution didn’t work, but I have a new one which is much cooler for just a byte longer.

Consider this input:

```
["  _   _                  "
 " | | | |    _            "
 " | | | |   | |         _ "
 " | | | |   | |     _  | |"
 "_| |_| |___| |____| |_| |"]
```

First, `=@|` makes a boolean matrix of where pipes are in the input.

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

Then sum `/+` the columns:

```
[0 4 0 4 0 4 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 2]
```

[Jonathan Allan's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129112/108687) uses the same idea of summing the mask of pipes, but in Jelly the shortest way to then get just the relevant numbers is to remove zeros and keep the items at even indices. In Uiua, that comes out to 14 bytes.

Instead, my idea was to first take the signs `±` of the sums:

```
[0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
```

and to scan `\` by not equal to `≠`:

```
[0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
```

Then, we take the minimums `↧` of this and the original sums:

```
[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

Using this as a filter `▽` for the sums yields the final result:

```
[4 4 3]
```

Comment: This returns the wrong answer when there are adjacent monoliths of the same height (for example it returns `[1]` instead of `[1,1,1]` for the third test case).

Comment: @Lynn Aw man. Well now I have a more interesting solution at the cost of two bytes. Time to remove my gloating remark :P

Comment: Now it’s just a byte longer than before :)

Comment: Here's another 12 char Uiua solution I came up with: [`▽\≠±.⊜⧻.⍉=@|`](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__JCAgIF8KJCAgfCB8ICAgICAgICBfCiQgIHwgfCAgXyAgICB8IHwKJCAgfCB8IHwgfCAgIHwgfCAgICAgXwokIF98IHxffCB8X19ffCB8X19fX3wgfF8KUGFyc2Ug4oaQIOKsmkAg4oqc4oiY4omgQFxuLgpTb2x2ZSDihpAg4pa9XOKJoMKxLuKKnOKnuy7ijYk9QHwKU29sdmUgUGFyc2UK)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <strike>48</strike> <strike>47</strike> 39 bytes

```
Last/@(Reverse@Most@#~Position~"_")&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLCsIwELznK0IEURCKepRCxKtCUW@1hKCtDWhTkkUQxF@veUppEzY7O@zshH1yqMVVd12V7rmGhM7Oije6lbqkx/JVKpMPUgOdfDOpBQjZfAkj8@kGIZC7mqutUvydZvx2FPcackvxKxhhQk@gRHM/tQ8B@WRBLg0pCicsNSzTnjwnCGOG8MfccGLFbGGQL31DbGOIGeiChdclUgST1cgE9@b/jxvvnfpmjvGgZxTB32Q9NLEyHyg2h89ZUZeZpQCmuDLhNoHQkFqNqXX3Aw)

`Function` which expects a rectangular array of characters. Takes `Most` of the array (all but the last row), `Reverse`s it, then takes the `Transpose`*, then finds all `Position`s at which the `_` character appears. The relevant heights are the `Last` elements of each `Position`.

* `` is the `3` byte private use character [`U+F3C7`](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2BF3C7) which represents [`\[Transpose]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Transpose.html.en) in Mathematica. Note that this doesn't work in [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), so the [TIO link](https://tio.run/##ZVDLCsIwELznK0IEURCKepRCxKtCUW@1hKCtDWhTkkUQxF@veUppEzY7O@zshH1yqMVVd12V7rmGhM7Oije6lbqkx/JVKpMPUgOdfDOpBQjZfAkj8@kGIZC7mqutUvydZvx2FPcackvxKxhhQk@gRHM/tQ8B@WRBLg0pCicsNSzTnjwnCGOG8MfccGLFbGGQL31DbGOIGeiChdclUgST1cgE9@b/jxvvnfpmjvGgZxTB32Q9NLEyHyg2h89ZUZeZpQCmuDLhNoHQkFqNqXX3Aw) just uses `Transpose`.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <strike>108</strike> <strike>104</strike> 88 bytes

Saved 16 bytes thanks to @JustinMariner

```
i=>i.map((s,h)=>{while(t=r.exec(s))m[t.index]=i.length-h-1},m=[],r=/_/g)&&m.filter(e=>e)
```

Input taken as an array of strings

```js
let input = [
'  _',
' | |           _',
' | |  _   _   | |',
' | | | | | |  | |     _',
'_| |_| |_| |__| |____| |_'
]

let anonymousFunction =
i=>i.map((s,h)=>{while(t=r.exec(s))m[t.index]=i.length-h-1},m=[],r=/_/g)&&m.filter(e=>e)

console.log(anonymousFunction(input))
```

Comment: 88 bytes [here](https://tio.run/##ZVDRqsIwDH3fV/TJtbBV/IDs8f7EGKPOuOXSpmPt7lXUb5/T4RTM4SScQ8KB/Jo/E5qB@pjvzR5tzv6Ak8UoiPsxChBlkgpRp9k8rjPe9eHVYuEsVvOF9eq5X89q5dKWkSZVkjxyDXs@Oz@Gn5GbSJ4FTAQFaWd6KUPWKSgu/x1ZlBEGjSdsZFDKlVETH/BUAWmL3MYu7/LdLXNQVtkA23rbqs3G6SPZiINEKFBNjefgLWrrW/kVLJ8vUGq6Aw)

Comment: Thanks @JustinMariner! I'm stoked about the variable initialization as unused parameters given to `Array.map`, that's a cool trick.

Comment: Do you really need to assign the RegEx to a variable? You could use it directly in the `exec` and save a few bytes.

Comment: Actually, it is necessary - the while loop iterates over each match on a line, and without the internal state of the regex in the variable it would match the first occurance each time and loop infinitely. Each iteration it would create a new regex so `exec` would match the first. It actually crashes the stack exchange snippet editor if you inline the regex. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @shaggy I forgot to tag you in my last comment

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 82 bytes

Takes in a list of lines.

```ruby
->l{l.map! &:chars;(l.pop.zip(*l).map{|s|s.join.count ?|}-[i=0]).select{0<1&i+=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYlBDoIwEEX3nKImhoCGCWyV6kGQNFhLLBnbhsJCac9eURJxkj//vZl@vD5DSy8hO@GE8GjMhsQHfm96e0wQjDbwkibZYfr5Tc46C52WCrge1UDOzmeVpHmdghUo@DDlZRHLPS28D4a01baEXjQ3QKmErQNZh0UrO@JmY/82r@WyQMTm/uYHbw)

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

<sup>1 byte saved thanks to @BusinessCat</sup>

```
{W%z'_f#{0>},}
```

This is a block that takes an array of strings on the stack and outputs an array.

#### Explanation:

```
W%    e# Reverse
z     e# Zip
'_f#  e# Get the index of '_' in each element (-1 if not found)
{0>}, e# Filter where positive
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by reversing the whole array before transposing.

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
I{ _WH╥?O
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=SSU3QiUyMF9XSCV1MjU2NSUzRk8_)
Takes input as an array of arrays of strings (characters).

Explanation:

```
I          rotate the array clockwise
 {         for each element
   _       push "_"
    W      get its index in the array (0 if not found, 1 if its the ground, >1 if its what we need)
     H     decrease that
      ╥    palindromize (duplicates the number, if it's <0, then errors and pushes 0, if =0, pushes 0, if >0, then pushes the number palindromized (always truthy))
       ?   if that, then
        T  output in a new line the original decreased index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 13 bytes

```
+1↘1⍜⍉⊚↘1⇌=@_
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAgKzHihpgx4o2c4o2J4oqa4oaYMeKHjD1AXwoKRiBbIiAgXyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAgICIgfCB8ICAgICAgICBfICAgICAgICAgIgogICAiIHwgfCAgXyAgICB8IHwgICAgICAgICIKICAgIiB8IHwgfCB8ICAgfCB8ICAgICBfICAiCiAgICJffCB8X3wgfF9fX3wgfF9fX198IHxfIl0KCkYgWyIgICAgICAgICAgIF8gICAgICAiCiAgICIgICAgICAgICAgfCB8ICAgICAiCiAgICIgIF8gICAgICAgfCB8ICAgICAiCiAgICIgfCB8ICBfICAgfCB8ICBfICAiCiAgICJffCB8X3wgfF9ffCB8X3wgfF8iXQoKRiBbIiBfICAgXyAgIF8gICAgICAiCiAgICJ8IHxffCB8X3wgfF9fX19fIl0K)

```
+1↘1⍜⍉⊚↘1⇌=@_
          =@_  # matrix mask of underscores
         ⇌     # reverse order of rows
       ↘1      # drop the first, removing the "floor"
    ⍜⍉⊚        # coordinates in the mask were it to be transposed
  ↘1           # drop the x coordinates
+1             # increment
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 12 bytes

```
+1▽⊃∊⊗@_⍉↘1⇌
```

[See it in action](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__TW9ub2xpdGhzIOKGkCArMeKWveKKg-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)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73 bytes

More boring but shorter than my original solution (below). Takes an array of lines.

```ruby
->s{s.pop
s.map(&:chars).transpose.filter_map{n=_1.index ?_
n&&s.size-n}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3PXXtiquL9QryC7iK9XITCzTUrJIzEouKNfVKihLzigvyi1P10jJzSlKL4oGy1Xm28YZ6mXkpqRUK9vFceWpqxXrFmVWpunm1tRADbzE-LVBwi1ZSUIhXwARcCjVACAXx6MJgASQFEGGIAEwYqIYrHsgB43goCaa4lPRyMvNSi2O5uKAuUECziQshAjOOC-EMhBDcMTAGko0wBoZt8VB7YHbBFEJdiE0DSA3RGJvvYE7HTXOB2DBv4KFRnIsHw50Bie0FCyA0AA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->s,*a{s.scan(/_/){c=$'.count $/
a<<[$`[/.+\Z/].size,c]if c>0}
a.sort.map{_2}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3_XTtinW0EquL9YqTE_M09OP1NauTbVXU9ZLzS_NKFFT0uRJtbKJVEqL19bRjovRj9Yozq1J1kmMz0xSS7QxquRL1ivOLSvRyEwuq441qayGm3mJsLlBwi1ZSUIjnUqgBQiiA8eJBHCALwoUogCmL54oHMsE4HkqCKaVYLi6ooQpI5sEB2DiIyciGg0UgDCSDYQyEoSBlEMwFk4RajqwIJEcsRnUwzGE4aS4QE-ZiPDSK8_BgpVhIXCxYAKEB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 44 bytes

```perl
s/_/$r[pos]=$./eg}{$_&&$.-$_&&say$.-$_ for@r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP15fpSi6IL841lZFTz81vbZaJV5NTUVPF0QVJ1aCWQpp@UUORf//K4BAvIICfpoLxKwBQgI0FxDHE4H/5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0@K9bAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

```javascript
a=>[...a.pop()].flatMap((_,i)=>a.flatMap((s,j)=>s[i]>_?a.length-j:[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3dCsMgDIXvfQovFdpAbwftnmBP0EkMne0sojJlV3t35/rDEpKc73AgK70pTS8bc@vDw5S5L9QPIwAQxBCFVDA7yjeKQmBjZT/Q30jNWo00WjXglcAZv@Rnu15GJWWZgk/BGXBhEbPQjHNk/FP7qJPwB1XtuAfOGDKschs89naYhuTsZETXtJ2EFJ3N@u51ffsF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

15 bytes of code, +2 for `-rp` flags.

```
_FI_@?'_MRVgZDs
```

Takes input from stdin. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/3s0z3sFePd43KCw9yqX4/38FhXguhRoghAIYLx7EAbIgXIgCmLJ4rnggE4zjoSSY@q9bVAAA)

#### Explanation

```
                 g is list of lines from stdin (-r flag); s is space
         RVg     Reverse g
            ZDs  Zip (transpose), filling gaps with a default char of space
        M        Map this function:
   _@?'_          Index of _ in each line (or nil if it doesn't appear)
_FI              Filter, keeping only the truthy (nonzero, non-nil) values
                 Autoprint in repr format (-p flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>19</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
f>T0mx_d\_.tQd
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%3ET0mx_d%5C_.tQd&input=%5B%22++_%22%2C%22+%7C+%7C++++++++_%22%2C%22+%7C+%7C++_++++%7C+%7C%22%2C%22+%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C+++%7C+%7C+++++_%22%2C%22_%7C+%7C_%7C+%7C___%7C+%7C____%7C+%7C_%22%5D&debug=0) The input is a list of lines.

**Explanations**

```
          .tQd     # Transpose, pad with spaces
    mx_d\_         # For each line, reverse it, find the position of "_" (-1 if not found)
f>T0               # Filter on positions greater than zero
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 31 bytes

```matlab
@(a)(s=sum(a>95))(s>0)(1:2:end)
```

Takes a 2D array of chars as input.

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/##pVLdDoIgFL6Opzh3wF22dZHO1ns0x5ji1kxtod2Yz25Hj@Bsy5tg55ePj49BnTb6ZYbhIrQUNrZtKfT5dJRYnPdSBOEhNFUmhzzWlY1YY2yTamssxNCxK@MAiqN/45zHUquxxMw1COSgI05hMZma/RR4wogaVpx@zJTEvz5i6lGyoncJT8YNjPhHLBliHWLW4ZETkNb/8olnA1ik/4yc9Lk7bcQv7RtGGvoIr5/XTyjwDYMQqrY0d@EfVjK2y272IfKlB13RS8nwIwwf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 65 bytes

```
{m:ex/^^(\N+)_([\N*\n]+:)/.sort(*[0].chars).map(+*[1].comb("
"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtcqtUI/Lk4jxk9bM14jOsZPKyYvVttKU1@vOL@oREMr2iBWLzkjsahYUy83sUBDWyvaECiQn5ukocSlpKlZ@99aoTixUiFNozintKgAqDQ/t0DzvwIIxCso4Ke5QMwaICRAcwFxPBEYAA)

- `m:exhaustive/^^(\N+)_([\N*\n]+:)/` searches the input string for all underscores, and returns a match object for each, where the first capturing parentheses contain the preceding part of the line on which the underscore is found, and the second capturing parentheses contain the entire rest of the string.  The rest of the string must contain at least one newline, so we don't count the underscores at ground level.  The `:exhaustive` flag allows these matches to overlap.
- `.sort(*[0].chars)` sorts these match objects by the number of characters in the part of the line preceding each underscore.  This orders them left-to-right.
- `.map(+*[1].comb("\n"))` maps each match object to the number of newline characters in the part of the input string trailing each underscore--that is, the height.  The `\n` is an actual newline character, saving one byte.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 119 bytes

```
function($s){$r=array_map(null,...$s);foreach($r as$k=>&$v)if($v=array_count_values($v)['|'])echo($v+$r[$k+2]=0)." ";};
```

Let's break this down! Our input here is a 2D array of chars.

```
$r=array_map(null,...$s) // Neat little snippet to transpose the array

foreach($r as$k=>&$v)    // Loop through the array, grabbing each row of our 2D array 
(which is now each column of the monolith)

if($v=array_count_values($v)['|']) // Count the number of '|' characters in the column 
(which is the height of our monolith), and if it's greater than 0 (truthy in PHP)...

echo($v+$r[$k+2]=0)." "; // Output that number, and simultaneously set the row 2 indices
                            down to null (to remove duplicate values)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of lines.

```
Õ®x2 èSÃf
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=tw&code=1a54MiDoU8Nm&input=IiAgXwogfCB8ICAgICAgICBfCiB8IHwgIF8gICAgfCB8CiB8IHwgfCB8ICAgfCB8ICAgICBfCl98IHxffCB8X19ffCB8X19fX3wgfF8i) (header splits input string to array) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=tw&code=1a54MiDoU8Nm&input=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)

```
Õ®x2 èSÃf     :Implicit input of array
Õ             :Transpose
 ®            :Map
  x2          :  Trim left
     è        :  Count
      S       :    Spaces
       Ã      :End map
        f     :Filter
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ṖZ=”_UT€F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmlRto8a5saHhjxqWuP2/@HuLYfbNf//j@ZSUlJSUIjnUqgBQiiA8eJBHCALwoUogCmL54oHMsE4HkqCKaBxOhAzFZCMgwOwaRCDkc0Gi0AYSObCGHAzQaogmAsmB7Ua1V6Y@ThpLhATZjEeGsUaPBhoMVcsAA)

Unfortunately, [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129112/66833) is still shorter, as I assume input is a list of lines, so don't count the `Ỵ`. However, I reckon this is an interesting enough approach to post

### How it works

```
ṖZ=”_UT€F - Main link. Takes a list of lines L on the left
Ṗ         - Remove the last line
 Z        - Transpose
  =”_     - Check each character for equality with "_"
     U    - Reverse each row
       €  - For each row
      T   - Yield the indices of 1
        F - Flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>114</s> 99 bytes

```r
\(u){`+`=length
for(j in 2:+u-1){F=c(a<-which(u[[j]]=="_"),F)
T=c(rep(+u-j,+a),T)}
T[order(F)][-1]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVLNaoQwEKbXPEXIKcPGgz2V0ly99eYthqxYrYq4EpUubPdJerGFPlR773s0mmR_YLt0wmS--ftmIHl719NHwT_HoQjuvrKEjrBbr9a8ydvnoUTFRtMaVy2-vV-NQQi7iGc0fQheyior6ShELSXnRBFgEaDYJHXeUVNas1UKLIY9isVGP-WaRiBFEMq9HfV987PlTdUPFBGMFcKv5jjxnpqdGVnfVvg6hZEyeFHl7sUQNjPiE7KDmDRytN47DLLghNODhU9h7BT5uBvp8nP4v-o29Hv8adEM_YJX7NlKVxQTQOgx7WhCayhoP-i-a6rhCGpGkpaAEKGUjBAAtjUdlyqJuiDmExz7YSFA9rWnydpf)

---

The monoliths are looking like barplots, and so, it is natural to use R. Surprisingly though, nobody has yet golfed this in R.

- The function takes as an input a list of vectors (1D arrays) of chacters; I have added `strsplit`s to the function call (see the link below) for better readability
- `f(strsplit(strsplit("____________________","\n")[[1]],""))` throws an error

**History:**

- -14 bytes thanks to pajonk
- -1 byte golfed myself

Comment: Nice solution! Some golfs for -14 bytes: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVLBasMwDIUd9RXGJ4s4h-40xvwXubnGLW2yJJS0qAk9ZPmSXbLBPmr7mjl13HVsLamMrCcs6UnCr2_Uv2fqo6mz-OFzPRcNtotooTZp9VznQKrtINuSKFlRsfvHqIln2JJaieVTfMiLVS4arUtjlOKWoySExD1SuhMutJTREmWCHSR6S-uUBKHpPNfXnc7Evqb9blPUPwA4YxbYizujBM8OzoC87yNCnGVgHT6qHe-j4ZLPK45az4yRnCPCJVZ2RngSVwJG6uCdmvHgjDeAyZyWsVEh5I6t31BjSJ2qN2wjzHzRwgDDMq7YX6NdUTatOW7_kT-p_o_1vbff

Comment: @pajonk impressive golfing! would you like to write your own answer?

Comment: Nah, the core algorithm is yours, from me just some minor improvements.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 20 bytes

```
fl gt0<fa"_"~<<tx<Rv
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYttabZpOQrpJQY2aYlK8Up1NjYlFTZBZRDJm1tKUotLFGy5FBSiFZQUFOIVMIESUFIHKFkDhFAQj10SLIykDFkSIgyTjIdLxgOFwDgeSoIpkGQsF1duYmaegq1CSj6QW1CkoKKQpgByL8TtCxZAaAA)

Some late night golfing, I'll probably find a way shorter version tomorrow.

### Explanation

- `Rv` reverse the rows
- `tx` transpose
- `fa"_"` find the index of `_` in the column ignoring columns without a `_`
- `fl gt0` remove 0s

### Reflection

- All of the following presets with `_` could have been useful here:

  - `ce '_'`
  - `e '_'`
  - `fa"_"`
- Related to that it might be nice to have  a version of `ce` which takes a list and counts all elements in that list appearing in the input.  This would be generally useful but would also save a byte on using `ce` to find specific characters.
- `eq0` is 3 bytes, but seems generally useful. If it were 2 bytes we could do `fn q0` here instead of `fl gt0` to save a byte.